# set size of a plot area in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to directly specify width and height of the **plot area** with `ggplot2`, for example 3" and 4" for the figure below?

[image]

Sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(-5,5,by=.1)
d <- data.frame(x=x,y=cos(x))
p <- ggplot(d) + aes(x=x,y=y) + geom_line()
ggsave(p,file='~/example.pdf')
```

Comment: You can set the aspect ratio to 4:3 with by adding `theme(aspect.ratio=4/3)`. The physical size of the plot will depend on the height and width arguments to `ggsave`, but adding the `theme` statement will maintain a 4:3 aspect ratio no matter what height and width you choose.

Comment: @Baptiste's [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571198/how-achieve-identical-facet-sizes-and-scales-in-several-multi-facet-ggplot2-grah/30571289#30571289) will do what you want.