# What if there are too many bars and they overlap with each other

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I was drawing a horizontal barplot using ggplot2. x is Metropolitan Statistical Area of US, and y is a indicator denoting the wage inequality level of immigrants.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(dc1980ineqimgrt, aes(x = msa, y = ineqimgrt)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
    coord_flip() + 
    labs(x = "MSA", y = "High immigrant wage / Low immigrant wage")
```

[The barplot I got is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnqEr.png)

It turns out that since there are more than 200 MSAs in US, the screen is too small to present clearly the barplot. And some bars and labels overlap with each other. I want to export a very long barplot (instead of a length the same as my laptop), which I think may solve this problem.

Is there any approach to deal with this problem?

Comment: You can export graphs with `pdf` or  `jpeg` or others. Look at `?pdf` or `?jpeg`

Comment: See `?ggsave` and modify the `height` argument.

Comment: It would also probably look a lot better if you did it in R's API to Google Viz (IMHO). You wouldn't have the issue with overlapping bars and it's just generally better looking.

Comment: would also be good if you provided your data

Answer (score 0):

The code given in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649435/set-size-of-a-plot-area-in-ggplot2) should provide a template for you to work with.

```
plot <- ggplot() ....
pdf(file="example.pdf", width=3, height=4)
print(plot)
dev.off()
```