# Set y axis label position ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am looking for graphic help using ggplot2.
I am plotting to different variables (A and B) against the same variable C. Variable A has values from -20 to 20, whereas variable B has values from -2 to 2. When using ggplot2, the y-axis-label is further away from the axis line for variable A than for variable B, as 20 takes more space than 2 and the label has the same distance to the numbers.

I would like to have the same distance for both. Is there a possibility of defining the distance between the axis label and the line?

I have tried working with theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=) ) but this makes it very hard to set the distance equally.

I also tried adding "\n" after my yaxis title, as suggested here (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/mK9DR3dKIBU) but this does not resolve my problem either.

An example using the PlantGrowth data:

```
  bp <- ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight)) +
        geom_boxplot()+
        theme_classic(base_size=16) +
        ylim(c(3,7))+
        coord_fixed(ratio=(3)/(4))

bp1000 <- ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight*1000)) +
        geom_boxplot()+
        theme_classic(base_size=16) +
        ylim(c(3000,7000))+
        coord_fixed(ratio=(3)/(4000))
```

you will see that the label of the y axis ("weight") is further away from the axis for bp1000 than for bp, even if with coord_fixed() it is quite easy to keep the plotting area the same.

How can I define that the distance for the ylabel for bp should be the same (i.e. longer) as for bp1000.

Comment: Make an example. Make it an easily reproducible, minimal example. You can use your real data (share with `dput()`), simulated data, or the easiest choice, built-in data (maybe `mtcars`, with `hp` and `mpg` vs `wt`). Show the code you tried, and then we can help where you're stuck and find code that works.

Comment: if you're trying to align two different plots (that's what I infer from the question), try searching for `rbind_gtable` examples here, it will solve the alignment issue.

Comment: Other possibility would be to use `facet_wrap` maybe with `scales='free_y'` setting.

Comment: @baptiste I looked up rbind_gtable and it is approximately what I want to do, except that I would like to create the plots independently and save as independant jpg files, that I could then eventually align manually. As in rbind_gtable where the two y.labels are at the same distance from the y.axis, I would like to set this distance myself. Is that possible or only when you bind the plots together?

Comment: I believe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30571289/471093) should work for you

Comment: but please, reconsider your use of jpeg, it's almost never the right format for R graphics (but good for photos). png, svg, pdf are usually better choices.

Comment: @baptiste Thank's for the tip for using png instead of jpg. I did not know that. For the answer you posted - the code unfortunately does not help. When I run it, it gives me the same output as I acheived at the moment, that is, it fixes the plotting area, but the distance between the y axis line and the y-axis label is still dependent on the size of the numbers of the scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the width manually to a physical unit (one inch in this example, for exaggeration)

```
g1 <- ggplotGrob(bp)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(bp1000)
g1$widths[3] <- g2$widths[3] <- list(unit(1,"in"))
grid.newpage()
grid.arrange(g1, g2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was for! Is there any good documentation about the different meanings of the grob class?

Comment: not really, but have a look [here](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/arrange-ggplot) and [there](https://github.com/baptiste/gtable/wiki/Description) for loosely related gtable stuff