# fix size of multiple plots in grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, gridextra

I have created a function `plot_output` that generates multiple plots depending on the inputs provided. I want to fix the size of each of the plots, and also, I do not want the size of the plot to vary with the number of plots displayed. I want the size of plots to stay fixed irrespective of the number of plots displayed. I am using diamonds dataset provided in R for my analysis. Can anyone please help me here?

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(gridExtra)

 data.diamonds<-data.frame(diamonds)

  plot_output<-function(data, var1, var2, var)
 {


 length_vars<-length(var)
 print(length_vars)

p<-list()
g<-list()

for( i in 1:length_vars)
{
 p[[i]]<-ggplot(data, aes_string(y=var1, x=var[i]))+geom_point()
  g[[i]]<-ggplot(data, aes_string(y=var2, x=var[i]))+geom_point()
 }


do.call("grid.arrange", c(p,g,  list(ncol=2)))


}

plot_output(data.diamonds, "price", "depth", var=c("cut","x"))
```

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571198/how-achieve-identical-facet-sizes-and-scales-in-several-multi-facet-ggplot2-grah/30571289#30571289

Comment: @baptiste - thanks for your response. My program is generating plots dynamically. Currently, with every addition of a plot, it resizes itself to be within the grid window. That makes it small and difficult to view. Can I make the window scrollable so that new plots stay of same size and its easy to view them. Can you please guide on how do I do that? sorry for the confusion in the earlier post. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know of a graphics device that is scrollable. Maybe you could embed the plots in a html or pdf document using knitr.

Comment: I want to display these plots on r shiny. Is it possible?

Comment: i don't know, but you should edit your question to make this clear.

Comment: okay, will post a new problem.