# Align Multiple plots in R, with the same x-axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I want to plot multiple time-series figures. I want them to be aligned on the same x axis.

However, due to the different quantity of y in the different plots, it is hard to simply plot them together. Y-labels take different space.

Is there any other way to align x-axis.

```
grid.newpage() 
pushViewport( viewport( layout=grid.layout( 4, 1 ) ) ) 
vplayout<-function( x, y ) viewport( layout.pos.row=x, layout.pos.col=y ) 
print( plot1, vp=vplayout( 1, 1 ) )
print( plot2, vp=vplayout( 2, 1 ) ) 
print( plot3, vp=vplayout( 3, 1 ) ) 
print( plot4, vp=vplayout( 4, 1 ) )
```

[image]

Comment: what package are you using for plotting? as far as I know this would be easy in base R. It would also help to have a reproducible example.

Comment: to plot multiple images, I used grid. The image is plot by ggplot. Please note, the above figure is just one image.

Comment: Check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571198/how-achieve-identical-facet-sizes-and-scales-in-several-multi-facet-ggplot2-grah/30571289#30571289

Comment: BTW, you could simply use a scientific notation for the Y axis, which will automatically fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you reshape the data and use facet_wrap it should work for your requirements.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
testdata<-as.data.frame(cbind(x=1:100, y1=rnorm(50), y2=100000*rnorm(50)))
testdata.melt<- melt(testdata, id.var = 'x')
ggplot(testdata.melt, aes(x = x, y = value, group = variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")
```

The resulting graph is:
[image]